# trying to insert object at certain index in list (c++)

Tags: c++, list, object, iterator

I'm trying to insert an object in a list of objects at a certain index, but my iterator doesn't seem to want to be added to an int. here is my code :

```
list<Node> nodes;
. . .
// filling list 
. . . 
void DiffLine::addNodeAt(int i, Node node) {
std::list<Node>::iterator it;
it = nodes.begin() + i;
nodes.insert(it, node);
}
```

and here is the error message that I am getting

> Error (active)    E0349   no operator "+" matches these operands

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std::list is not random-access so its iterators are not randomly advanceable *on purpose*. There's `std::advance()` in the header `<iterator>` if you really want to advance it, just be ready to wait for a linear time. And consider using `std::vector`.

Comment: Note that the behaviour is not defined if `advance` advances past the end of the container. Be certain that `i` is valid before calling.